# Windows scheduler — how does fair time slicing work?

Tags: windows, multithreading, scheduler, scheduling, windows-kernel

Windows internals ([go to Quantum End section](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233328&seqNum=7#Quantum_End)) states how previous versions of Windows used to unfairly penalise threads but since Vista, it now longer charges threads that start half way through a clock interval or for interrupt processing.

I am familiar with the ReactOS kernel and the Windows Research Kernel source code. The `KiQuantumEnd` function is called by `KiDispatchinterrupt` which is most likely called by the software interrupt which gets requested when the quantum expires i.e. a thread starts with 6 quantum units and 3 are subtracted every clock interrupt and when it is greater than or equal to 0 the clock interrupt ISR (`KiUpdateRunTime`) requests a Self IPI. `KiQuantumEnd` is only documented on ReactOS and as ReactOS exhibits XP behaviour it does not check for unfair penalisation and just schedules and dispatches a new thread.

Obviously on Windows Vista and onwards it would be implemented differently but the WRK doesn't expose that function so I can't look into it. I wish I knew how it actually implements the fair time slicing that is stated on windows internals.

The only way I can think of would be the generic interrupt handler (the undocumented `KiInterruptDispatch`) that is registered at all nonchained ISR entries that calls the ISR from the interrupt object could potentially do a `RDTSC` if nesting level is 1 then increment the nesting level and at the end of interrupt when `KiInterruptDispatch` returns, decrease the nesting level and if it's equal to 1 it could do another `RDTSC` and store the difference between the two in a member of the thread object (this way the outer interrupt keeps the timing). This of course wouldn't count for SMIs and it does contradict the wording of the windows internals section which suggests there is a total number of cycles racked up by the thread which is recorded but it sounds far less practical than the method I suggested. It makes sense to record in the thread object the amount of cycles lost rather than those charged to the thread and I can't think of any practical way that it would keep track of that.

As for the scenario where a thread is scheduled in mid clock interval, the only way I can think of how it does it is by the scheduling code taking an `RDTSC` and storing it in a separate thread member and then `KiQuantumEnd` doing an `RDTSC`, subtracting the original value recorded when it was scheduled and then subtracting the other member which records cycles lost and then comparing to the target amount of cycles.

There are interesting fields in the `KTHREAD` structure such as 'CycleTime' and 'CurrentRunTime'.

If anyone knows of any other implementation or the actual implementation then please let me know.

Comment: This is all thoroughly undocumented.  For a good reason, it is the way Microsoft innovates on new Windows versions.  Like they did in Win8, you can safely assume that the thread context switcher uses RDTSC since there is no other way to implement the documented QueryThreadCycleTime() and friends.